# How to change the tool-tip's font and background color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With older, color challenged eyes I find it hard to read the small, white font used in tool-tips against the tool-tip's grey background.

I am looking for the name of the settings which controls the font color and the background color. Also, where are said settings stored, i.e. what is the fully qualified filename? I'm working with both Windows and Linux (Win11, Win10, Ubuntu, and Raspberry Pi OS).

Comment: what do you mean with the word `tooltip`? Can you take a screenshot of it?

Comment: @TakashiAnji Tool tip usually means the text that appears (pops-up) when you hover over something with your mouse pointer. For example, if you hover over the voting buttons here on the site you will see text explaining you what they do

Comment: you can switch to the High Contrast Light/Dark Theme

Comment: @TakashiAnji is correct the tool tip is the text that appears when hovering.
Changing to any of the High Contrast themes does not change what I am seeing.

Comment: is this question about the hover info widget that appears when you hover over some text in an editor? Or is it about tooltips for UI buttons like action buttons?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

#### If this is what you want!

Add these to your setting.json

```json
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorHoverWidget.background": "#B98389"
  },
```

#### How did I found it?

- Open `setting.json`.
- Go inside `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` block.
- Type `"hover"` and read the suggestions.

#### About Setting.json

visit [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) link.

[image]

Comment: comment if you don't know how to use `setting.json`

Comment: Instead of waiting for a comment, just provide a link to the VS Code docs on [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), since explaining that would be too broad, imho.

Comment: @GinoMempin oh, thanks. the way he's asking "kind of" show that he know it. So I just say that. *editing...

Comment: Takashi Anji: that is almost what I want, as it does change the background for the hover tips for highlighted keywords within a workbench.  A tool tip example of my concern can be found when hovering over the three dots at the extreme upper right-hand corner of your first screen shot.  (I haven't a clue about capturing the hover text in a screen shot.)  On my installation those three dots yield a tool tip text of "More actions..." rendered in white text on a grey background.

Comment: @RichMcDonald I tried some, but still no hope .__.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open The Vs Code (visual Studio code).
2. Click the top left side file menu.
3. Click preferences and in side of 3rd row Click themes.
   enjoy you visual studio code.

Comment: thats not what he asked.